# Playing Facebook Games

Tags: 14.04, facebook

I love playing City Girl on Facebook but have to switch between Ubuntu to Windows as mine is duel loading. I'm an absolute beginner with Ubuntu and I need simple answers on how can play it (if I can) or not on Ubuntu.

Comment: What happens when you try playing it on Ubuntu? Are there any errors encountered or how does it behave? Please give us some more info.

Comment: Nothing happens at all. Just has the game logo. I can collect gifts from the message centre but that's it. I've refreshed the page and tried a bit later but nothing changes.

Comment: How about other games, do they play? Which browser are you using and have you tried another browser?

Comment: I only play that one and I use Chromium.

Comment: I first thought it's a flash issue but Chromium has one built in. Which Chromium and Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.o4 LTS and Chromium 3.60

Comment: I'm running out of options here - can you watch youtube videos using Chromium?

Comment: Of course I can! I can also play games on Newgrounds

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503275/i-cant-play-any-online-games-on-facebook If not, I'll start a bounty for you in two days time when the bounty period starts to draw attention to this question.

Comment: Possibly due to user agent?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the flash is not working or is not installed 
but you can play it on mozilla firefox

if you do not have the firefox installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Then close all browsers & install the flash plugin

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

or

Install Fresh Player Plugin

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox either. Just tried

Comment: She also said it doesn't work with Pepper Flash Player in Chromium Web Browser.

Comment: how about adobe flash player ,? & check maybe the plugin is disabled in the browser